# Merge query in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'll admit I don't have a lot of DB experience as my last job had a DBA but this place has none. I have an existing MASSIVE stored procedure that I need to modify (I noticed a lot of duplication and cut that out).

Right now, it pulls so much data they used a cache table or the page crashes. They just want a smaller amount of data now for a separate page. I'm trying to edit this stored procedure and merge in my new query to it.

The existing stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PurchasingSupplyChainNeeds]
    (@maxAgeInHours INT = 24)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sqlStmt NVARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @myName NVARCHAR(max) = Object_name(@@PROCID)
    DECLARE @needsRefresh INT

    EXEC @needsRefresh = [cache].[NeedsRefresh]
        @myName,
        @maxAgeInHours

    IF @needsRefresh = 1
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @CurrentMonth INT
        DECLARE @DayOfWeek INT
        DECLARE @EndOfWeekDate DATETIME
        DECLARE @StartOfNextWeek DATETIME
        DECLARE @WorkDaysInMonth INT
        DECLARE @RunningDate DATE
        DECLARE @WorkDaysLeftInMonth INT
        DECLARE @DayOffset INT

        SELECT @CurrentMonth = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())
        SELECT @DayOfWeek = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())

        IF (@DayOfWeek = 1)
        BEGIN
            SET @StartOfNextWeek = GETDATE()
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @StartOfNextWeek = DATEADD(day, 8 - @DayOfWeek, GETDATE())
        END

        SELECT @DayOfWeek = DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE())

        IF (@DayOfWeek = 7)
        BEGIN
            SET @EndOfWeekDate = Getdate()
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @EndOfWeekDate = DATEADD(day, -@DayOfWeek, GETDATE())
        END

            SET @WorkDaysInMonth = 0
            SET @RunningDate = CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR, @CurrentMonth) + '/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(year, Getdate())))

            WHILE ( Datepart(month, @RunningDate) = @CurrentMonth )
              BEGIN
                  SET @DayOfWeek = Datepart(weekday, @RunningDate)

                  IF ( @DayOfWeek != 1
                       AND @DayOfWeek != 7 )
                    BEGIN
                        SET @WorkDaysInMonth = @WorkDaysInMonth + 1
                    END

                  SET @RunningDate = Dateadd(day, 1, @RunningDate)
              END

            SET @WorkDaysLeftInMonth = 0
            SET @DayOffset = 0

            WHILE ( Datepart(month, Dateadd(day, @DayOffset, Getdate())) = @CurrentMonth )
              BEGIN
                  SET @DayOfWeek = Datepart(weekday, Dateadd(day, @DayOffset, Getdate()))

                  IF ( @DayOfWeek != 1
                       AND @DayOfWeek != 7 )
                    BEGIN
                        SET @WorkDaysLeftInMonth = @WorkDaysLeftInMonth + 1
                    END

                  SET @DayOffset = @DayOffset + 1
              END;

            WITH j
                 AS (SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim(imitmidx_sql.item_no))                  AS ItemNo,
                            Rtrim(Ltrim(ISNULL(imitmidx_sql.item_desc_1, '')))  AS ItemDescription1,
                            Rtrim(Ltrim(ISNULL(imitmidx_sql.item_desc_2, '')))  AS ItemDescription2,
                            Rtrim(Ltrim(ISNULL(imitmidx_sql.activity_cd, '-'))) AS ActivityCode,
                            Rtrim(Ltrim(imitmidx_sql.pur_or_mfg))               AS PurchasedOrMfg,
                            Rtrim(Ltrim(ISNULL(imitmidx_sql.uom, '-')))         AS UOM,
                            /* 
                            case statements ensure the price, avg_cost & price
                            are only observed from the item's primary location;
                            not secondary locations such as Amazon warehouses
                            */
                            CASE
                              WHEN iminvloc_sql.loc = imitmidx_sql.loc THEN Rtrim(Ltrim(ISNULL(cicmpy.cmp_name, '')))
                              ELSE ''
                            END                                                 AS VendorName,
                            CASE
                              WHEN iminvloc_sql.loc = imitmidx_sql.loc THEN iminvloc_sql.avg_cost
                              ELSE 0
                            END                                                 AS AverageCost,
                            CASE
                              WHEN iminvloc_sql.loc = imitmidx_sql.loc THEN iminvloc_sql.price
                              ELSE 0
                            END                                                 AS Price,
                            iminvloc_sql.qty_on_hand                            AS QtyOnHand,
                            iminvloc_sql.qty_allocated                          AS QtyAllocated,
                            (SELECT ISNULL(qty_on_hand, 0)
                             FROM   iminvloc_sql WITH (NOLOCK)
                             WHERE  item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                    AND loc = '3IV')                            AS QtyIn3IV,
                            (SELECT ISNULL(qty_on_hand, 0)
                             FROM   iminvloc_sql WITH (NOLOCK)
                             WHERE  item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                    AND loc = '3TI')                            AS QtyIn3TI,
                            (SELECT ISNULL(qty_on_hand, 0)
                             FROM   iminvloc_sql WITH (NOLOCK)
                             WHERE  item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                    AND loc = '3FA')                            AS QtyIn3FA,
                            (SELECT ISNULL(Sum(qty_ordered), 0)
                             FROM   (SELECT y.qty_ordered
                                     FROM   oeordhdr_sql x WITH (NOLOCK)
                                            INNER JOIN oeordlin_sql y WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                    ON x.ord_type = y.ord_type
                                                       AND x.ord_no = y.ord_no
                                     WHERE  x.ord_type = 'O'
                                            AND x.entered_dt BETWEEN Dateadd(day, 1, Dateadd(week, -52, Cast(@EndOfWeekDate AS DATE))) AND Dateadd(week, -51, Cast(@EndOfWeekDate AS DATE))
                                            AND y.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                            AND y.loc = iminvloc_sql.loc
                                            AND x.status != 'L'
                                     UNION ALL
                                     SELECT y.qty_to_ship
                                     FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ord_type,
                                                             ord_no,
                                                             entered_dt
                                             FROM   oehdrhst_sql WITH (NOLOCK)
                                             WHERE  ord_type = 'O'
                                                    AND entered_dt BETWEEN Dateadd(day, 1, Dateadd(week, -52, Cast(@EndOfWeekDate AS DATE))) AND Dateadd(week, -51, Cast(@EndOfWeekDate AS DATE))) x
                                            INNER JOIN oelinhst_sql y WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                    ON x.ord_type = y.ord_type
                                                       AND x.ord_no = y.ord_no
                                     WHERE  y.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                            AND y.loc = iminvloc_sql.loc) s)    AS SalesWeek1,
                            ---Sales week 2 to 51 here
                            (SELECT ISNULL(Sum(qty_ordered), 0)
                             FROM   (SELECT y.qty_ordered
                                     FROM   oeordhdr_sql x WITH (NOLOCK)
                                            INNER JOIN oeordlin_sql y WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                    ON x.ord_type = y.ord_type
                                                       AND x.ord_no = y.ord_no
                                     WHERE  x.ord_type = 'O'
                                            AND x.entered_dt BETWEEN Dateadd(day, 1, Dateadd(week, -1, Cast(@EndOfWeekDate AS DATE))) AND @EndOfWeekDate
                                            AND y.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                            AND y.loc = iminvloc_sql.loc
                                            AND x.status != 'L'
                                     UNION ALL
                                     SELECT y.qty_to_ship
                                     FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ord_type,
                                                             ord_no,
                                                             entered_dt
                                             FROM   oehdrhst_sql WITH (NOLOCK)
                                             WHERE  ord_type = 'O'
                                                    AND entered_dt BETWEEN Dateadd(day, 1, Dateadd(week, -1, Cast(@EndOfWeekDate AS DATE))) AND @EndOfWeekDate) x
                                            INNER JOIN oelinhst_sql y WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                    ON x.ord_type = y.ord_type
                                                       AND x.ord_no = y.ord_no
                                     WHERE  y.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                            AND y.loc = iminvloc_sql.loc) s)    AS SalesWeek52,
                            (SELECT ISNULL(Sum(qty_ordered), 0)
                             FROM   (SELECT y.qty_ordered
                                     FROM   oeordhdr_sql x WITH (NOLOCK)
                                            INNER JOIN oeordlin_sql y WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                    ON x.ord_type = y.ord_type
                                                       AND x.ord_no = y.ord_no
                                     WHERE  x.ord_type = 'O'
                                            AND x.entered_dt BETWEEN Cast('1/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(year, Dateadd(year, -2, Getdate()))) AS DATE) AND Cast('1/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(year, Dateadd(year, -1, Getdate()))) AS DATE)
                                            AND y.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                            AND y.loc = iminvloc_sql.loc
                                            AND x.status != 'L'
                                     UNION ALL
                                     SELECT y.qty_to_ship
                                     FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ord_type,
                                                             ord_no,
                                                             entered_dt
                                             FROM   oehdrhst_sql WITH (NOLOCK)
                                             WHERE  ord_type = 'O'
                                                    AND entered_dt BETWEEN Cast('1/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(year, Dateadd(year, -2, Getdate()))) AS DATE) AND Cast('1/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(year, Dateadd(year, -1, Getdate()))) AS DATE)) x
                                            INNER JOIN oelinhst_sql y WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                    ON x.ord_type = y.ord_type
                                                       AND x.ord_no = y.ord_no
                                     WHERE  y.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                            AND y.loc = iminvloc_sql.loc) s)    AS SalesYear1,
                            (SELECT ISNULL(Sum(qty_ordered), 0)
                             FROM   (SELECT y.qty_ordered
                                     FROM   oeordhdr_sql x WITH (NOLOCK)
                                            INNER JOIN oeordlin_sql y WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                    ON x.ord_type = y.ord_type
                                                       AND x.ord_no = y.ord_no
                                     WHERE  x.ord_type = 'O'
                                            AND x.entered_dt BETWEEN Cast('1/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(year, Dateadd(year, -1, Getdate()))) AS DATE) AND Cast('1/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(year, Getdate())) AS DATE)
                                            AND y.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                            AND y.loc = iminvloc_sql.loc
                                            AND x.status != 'L'
                                     UNION ALL
                                     SELECT y.qty_to_ship
                                     FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ord_type,
                                                             ord_no,
                                                             entered_dt
                                             FROM   oehdrhst_sql WITH (NOLOCK)
                                             WHERE  ord_type = 'O'
                                                    AND entered_dt BETWEEN Cast('1/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(year, Dateadd(year, -1, Getdate()))) AS DATE) AND Cast('1/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(year, Getdate())) AS DATE)) x
                                            INNER JOIN oelinhst_sql y WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                    ON x.ord_type = y.ord_type
                                                       AND x.ord_no = y.ord_no
                                     WHERE  y.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                            AND y.loc = iminvloc_sql.loc) s)    AS SalesYear2,
                            (SELECT ISNULL(Sum(qty_ordered), 0)
                             FROM   (SELECT y.qty_ordered
                                     FROM   oeordhdr_sql x WITH (NOLOCK)
                                            INNER JOIN oeordlin_sql y WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                    ON x.ord_type = y.ord_type
                                                       AND x.ord_no = y.ord_no
                                     WHERE  x.ord_type = 'O'
                                            AND x.entered_dt BETWEEN Cast('1/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(year, Getdate())) AS DATE) AND Cast(Getdate() AS DATE)
                                            AND y.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                            AND y.loc = iminvloc_sql.loc
                                            AND x.status != 'L'
                                     UNION ALL
                                     SELECT y.qty_to_ship
                                     FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ord_type,
                                                             ord_no,
                                                             entered_dt
                                             FROM   oehdrhst_sql WITH (NOLOCK)
                                             WHERE  ord_type = 'O'
                                                    AND entered_dt BETWEEN Cast('1/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(year, Getdate())) AS DATE) AND Cast(Getdate() AS DATE)) x
                                            INNER JOIN oelinhst_sql y WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                    ON x.ord_type = y.ord_type
                                                       AND x.ord_no = y.ord_no
                                     WHERE  y.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                            AND y.loc = iminvloc_sql.loc) s)    AS SalesYTD,
                            CASE
                              WHEN Datediff(week, imitmidx_sql.activity_dt, Getdate()) > 52 THEN 52
                              ELSE Datediff(week, imitmidx_sql.activity_dt, Getdate())
                            END                                                 AS ActiveWeeks,
                            (SELECT ( ISNULL(ForecastQty, 0) / @WorkDaysInMonth ) * @WorkDaysLeftInMonth
                             FROM   HP_PurchasingForecast
                             WHERE  ItemNo = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                    AND [Month] = Datepart(month, Getdate())
                                    AND [Year] = Datepart(year, Getdate())
                                    AND Active = 1)                             AS RemainingForecastQty,
                            (SELECT ISNULL(ForecastQty, 0)
                             FROM   HP_PurchasingForecast
                             WHERE  ItemNo = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                    AND [Month] = Datepart(month, Getdate())
                                    AND [Year] = Datepart(year, Getdate())
                                    AND Active = 1)                             AS ForecastQty1,
                            ---ForecastQty 2 to 11
                            (SELECT ISNULL(ForecastQty, 0)
                             FROM   HP_PurchasingForecast
                             WHERE  ItemNo = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                    AND [Month] = Datepart(month, Dateadd(month, 11, Getdate()))
                                    AND [Year] = Datepart(year, Dateadd(month, 11, Getdate()))
                                    AND Active = 1)                             AS ForecastQty12,
                            ( (SELECT ISNULL(Sum(CASE
                                                   WHEN receipt_dt IS NULL THEN qty_ordered
                                                   ELSE qty_remaining
                                                 END), 0)
                               FROM   poordlin_sql WITH (NOLOCK)
                               WHERE  ord_status IN ( 'P', 'R' )
                                      AND item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                      AND promise_dt IS NOT NULL
                                      AND promise_dt <= CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(day, 6, @StartOfNextWeek))
                                      AND
                                      (
                                        receipt_dt IS NULL
                                         OR ISNULL(qty_remaining, 0) > 0
                                       )
                              )
                              + (SELECT ISNULL(Sum(y.quantity), 0)
                                 FROM   imtrnhdr_sql x WITH (NOLOCK)
                                        INNER JOIN imtrndtl_sql y WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                ON x.transit_no = y.transit_no
                                 WHERE  x.status IN ( 'A', 'S' )
                                        AND y.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                        AND x.to_loc = iminvloc_sql.loc
                                        AND x.due_date <= CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(day, 6, @StartOfNextWeek))
                                        AND NOT
                                            (
                                              x.from_loc = '3IV'
                                              AND x.temp_loc = '3TI'
                                              AND x.to_loc = iminvloc_sql.loc
                                             )
                                ) )                                             AS POQty1,
                          ---POQty 2 to 52
                            ( (SELECT ISNULL(Sum(CASE
                                                   WHEN receipt_dt IS NULL THEN qty_ordered
                                                   ELSE qty_remaining
                                                 END), 0)
                               FROM   poordlin_sql WITH (NOLOCK)
                               WHERE  ord_status IN ( 'P', 'R' )
                                      AND item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                      AND promise_dt IS NOT NULL
                                      AND promise_dt BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(day, 357, @StartOfNextWeek)) AND CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(day, 363, @StartOfNextWeek))
                                      AND
                                      (
                                        receipt_dt IS NULL
                                         OR ISNULL(qty_remaining, 0) > 0
                                       )
                              )
                              + (SELECT ISNULL(Sum(y.quantity), 0)
                                 FROM   imtrnhdr_sql x WITH (NOLOCK)
                                        INNER JOIN imtrndtl_sql y WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                ON x.transit_no = y.transit_no
                                 WHERE  x.status IN ( 'A', 'S' )
                                        AND y.item_no = imitmidx_sql.item_no
                                        AND x.to_loc = iminvloc_sql.loc
                                        AND x.due_date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(day, 357, @StartOfNextWeek)) AND CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(day, 363, @StartOfNextWeek))
                                        AND NOT
                                            (
                                              x.from_loc = '3IV'
                                              AND x.temp_loc = '3TI'
                                              AND x.to_loc = iminvloc_sql.loc
                                             )
                                ) )                                             AS POQty52
                     FROM   imitmidx_sql imitmidx_sql WITH (NOLOCK)
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN iminvloc_sql iminvloc_sql WITH (NOLOCK)
                                         ON imitmidx_sql.item_no = iminvloc_sql.item_no
                                            AND
                                            (
                                              imitmidx_sql.loc = iminvloc_sql.loc /* Primary location for the item */
                                               OR iminvloc_sql.loc = '3FA'/*Amazon Fullfillment Center*/
                                             )
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN cicmpy cicmpy
                                         ON iminvloc_sql.vend_no = cicmpy.cmp_code
                                            AND cicmpy.cmp_type = 'S'),
                 i
                 AS (SELECT [ItemNo],
                            [ItemDescription1],
                            [ItemDescription2],
                            [ActivityCode],
                            [PurchasedOrMfg],
                            [UOM],
                            Max([VendorName])           [VendorName],
                            Max([AverageCost])          [AverageCost],
                            Max([Price])                [Price],
                            Sum([QtyOnHand])            [QtyOnHand],
                            Sum([QtyAllocated])         [QtyAllocated],
                            Max([QtyIn3IV])             [QtyIn3IV],
                            Max([QtyIn3TI])             [QtyIn3TI],
                            Max([QtyIn3FA])             [QtyIn3FA],
                            Sum([SalesWeek1])           [SalesWeek1],
                         ---SalesWeek2 to 51
                     
                            Sum([SalesWeek52])          [SalesWeek52],
                            Sum([SalesYear1])           [SalesYear1],
                            Sum([SalesYear2])           [SalesYear2],
                            Sum([SalesYTD])             [SalesYTD],
                            Avg([ActiveWeeks])          [ActiveWeeks],
                            Avg([RemainingForecastQty]) [RemainingForecastQty],
                            Avg([ForecastQty1])         [ForecastQty1],
                          ---ForecastQty2 to 11
                            Avg([ForecastQty12])        [ForecastQty12],
                            Avg([POQty1])               [POQty1],
                           ---POQty2 to 51
                            Avg([POQty52])              [POQty52]
                     FROM   j
                     WHERE [PurchasedOrMfg] = 'M'
                     GROUP  BY [ItemNo],
                               [ItemDescription1],
                               [ItemDescription2],
                               [ActivityCode],
                               [PurchasedOrMfg],
                               [UOM])


            SELECT i.*,
                   CASE i.ActiveWeeks
                     WHEN 0 THEN 0
                     ELSE ( i.SalesWeek52 + i.SalesWeek51 + i.SalesWeek50 + i.SalesWeek49 + i.SalesWeek48 + i.SalesWeek47 ) /
                          (
                            CASE
                              WHEN i.ActiveWeeks < 6 THEN i.ActiveWeeks
                              ELSE 6
                            END
                          )
                   END                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               AS Last6WeeksAvg,
                   CASE i.ActiveWeeks
                     WHEN 0 THEN 0
                     ELSE ( i.SalesWeek52 + i.SalesWeek51 + i.SalesWeek50 + i.SalesWeek49 + i.SalesWeek48 + i.SalesWeek47 + i.SalesWeek46 + i.SalesWeek45 + i.SalesWeek44 + i.SalesWeek43 + i.SalesWeek42 + i.SalesWeek41 ) /
                          (
                            CASE
                              WHEN i.ActiveWeeks < 12 THEN i.ActiveWeeks
                              ELSE 12
                            END
                          )
                   END                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               AS Last12WeeksAvg,
                   CASE i.ActiveWeeks
                     WHEN 0 THEN 0
                     ELSE ( i.SalesWeek52 + i.SalesWeek51 + i.SalesWeek50 + i.SalesWeek49 + i.SalesWeek48 + i.SalesWeek47 + i.SalesWeek46 + i.SalesWeek45 + i.SalesWeek44 + i.SalesWeek43 + i.SalesWeek42 + i.SalesWeek41 + i.SalesWeek40 + i.SalesWeek39 + i.SalesWeek38 + i.SalesWeek37 + i.SalesWeek36 + i.SalesWeek35 + i.SalesWeek34 + i.SalesWeek33 + i.SalesWeek32 + i.SalesWeek31 + i.SalesWeek30 + i.SalesWeek29 + i.SalesWeek28 + i.SalesWeek27 + i.SalesWeek26 + i.SalesWeek25 + i.SalesWeek24 + i.SalesWeek23 + i.SalesWeek22 + i.SalesWeek21 + i.SalesWeek20 + i.SalesWeek19 + i.SalesWeek18 + i.SalesWeek17 + i.SalesWeek16 + i.SalesWeek15 + i.SalesWeek14 + i.SalesWeek13 + i.SalesWeek12 + i.SalesWeek11 + i.SalesWeek10 + i.SalesWeek9 + i.SalesWeek8 + i.SalesWeek7 + i.SalesWeek6 + i.SalesWeek5 + i.SalesWeek4 + i.SalesWeek3 + i.SalesWeek2 + i.SalesWeek1 ) / i.ActiveWeeks
                   END                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               AS Last52WeeksAvg,
                   ( ISNULL(i.RemainingForecastQty, 0) + ISNULL(i.ForecastQty2, 0) + ISNULL(i.ForecastQty3, 0) + ISNULL(i.ForecastQty4, 0) + ISNULL(i.ForecastQty5, 0) + ISNULL(i.ForecastQty6, 0) + ISNULL(i.ForecastQty7, 0) + ISNULL(i.ForecastQty8, 0) + ISNULL(i.ForecastQty9, 0) + ISNULL(i.ForecastQty10, 0) + ISNULL(i.ForecastQty11, 0) + ISNULL(i.ForecastQty12, 0) ) / 52 AS AvgWeeklyForecast,
                   ISNULL(i.QtyIn3FA, 0) + ISNULL(i.QtyOnHand, 0) + ISNULL(i.QtyIn3TI, 0) - ISNULL(i.QtyAllocated, 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                AS QtyAvailable
            INTO   #outputToCache
            FROM   i

            SET @sqlStmt = 'select * INTO [cache].[' + @myName + '] from #outputToCache'

            EXEC sp_executesql
              @sqlStmt
        END

      SET @sqlStmt = 'select * from [cache].[' + @myName + ']'

      EXEC sp_executesql
        @sqlStmt
  END
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
    tb_1.SubPart AS 'Sub Part',
    SUM(tb_1.FinalItemSubPartQuantity) 'Sub Part Quantity Needed',
    SUM(tb_1.FinalItemSubPartQuantity * tb_2.SalesWeek1) 'Total Sales Week 1',
    --- Total Sales Week 2 to 51 here
    SUM(tb_1.FinalItemSubPartQuantity * tb_2.SalesWeek52) 'Total Sales Week 52'
FROM 
    [009Reports].[dbo].[ANC Parts] tb_1
JOIN 
    [555].[cache].[PurchasingSupplyChainNeeds] tb_2 ON tb_1.FinalPartNo = tb_2.ItemNo
GROUP BY 
    tb_1.SubPart
```

Replacing this query below with mine:

```
AS (SELECT [ItemNo],
                            [ItemDescription1],
                            [ItemDescription2],
```

This is the error I get:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3168
> Invalid object name 'i'

My query has 2 different tables in 2 different databases.

Comment: *WHy* are you spamming that `NOLOCK` hint? Do you understand what the hint does? Why, if you *really* "need" it are you not changing the isolation of the query instead? I suggest you read [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: This was a store procedure I was given from the previous devs that left. I never wrote this and not familiar with a lot of db work as my last place had a DBA. I know with all the duplication this is poorly written but they didn't hire a DBA that would know this.

Comment: For the issue at hand nobody can help you. You say you are getting errors...what are they? We need a LOT more information to even pretend to help.

Comment: Honestly, I would just git rid of all those `NOLOCK` hints then, @PaulR . They were clearly be (ab)used by someone that didn't know what it does.

Comment: I don't really get what you want us to help you with. If I understand correctly, you're editing the SP and making a new query that takes data from the cache table that gets filled with the stored procedure, but you're getting "errors"; are the errors from your query or from the SP? exactly what kind of modifications you need to do to the SP? do you need help to modify the SP or to write the new query?

Comment: @JoshPart The section on the bottom shows "AS (SELECT [ItemNo],
                            [ItemDescription1],
                            [ItemDescription2]," Where you see this SELECT is where I would put my SELECT. That's what I had an issue with. Adding my query into the SP. I see an answer that I can't join it with my sp. Have to figure that out.

Comment: That's where you would ADD your query? or is your query goingo to REPLACE that query? The query you are pointing out (`SELECT [ItemNo]...`) is a subquery that's referenced as a subtable in the main query with an alias "i". I'm pretty sure you're "inserting" your query which "breaks" this as the "i" subtable no longer exists (it's a bit complicated, but I believe what you're trying to do isn't actually the solution to what you need to do)

Comment: @JoshPart Yes, I was replacing. Reason for the issue. Researching temp table...ugh.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad: it's neither a subquery nor a subtable, it's a CTE. That's what you should research. I'll write a (temporary) answer to help you better understand what's the issue you're facing, and possible issues you'll face after you replace the old query with the new one

Comment: BTW: could you please specify wich SQL Server version you're using?

Comment: @JoshPart Thanks Josh. I'm actually using SSMS v18.11.1

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the stored procedure is using [CTEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to create "temporary tables" based on (ugly and monstruous) queries and then use them to fill a table.

In general terms, a CTE is a table made from the results of a query, that's only usable by the immediate next query (this is: you create a CTE, then use it on a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE... then the CTE gets destroyed).

What the SP is doing is this:

1. Creates CTE `j` using info and calculations from certain tables
2. Uses info from CTE `j` to create CTE `i`
3. Uses info from CTE `i` to create a temporary table `#outputToCache`
4. Dumps info from `#outputToCache` into a physical table `cache.PurchasingSupplyChainNeeds`
5. `SELECT`s and returns the info from `cache.PurchasingSupplyChainNeeds` as the resultset from the stored procedure

The error you're getting is because you're replacing the creation of CTE `i` with your own query, but `i` is still used later on to fill the temporary table.

Now, you say that what you are trying to achieve, is to retrieve a smaller amount of data from this last "cache" table for a separate page. **IF I UNDERSTAND CORRECTLY** (emphasized because I'm not 100% sure I got it already) you shouldn't modify this stored procedure (this is, add your query into it) because that would change the output of it, and would break anything that uses it. Not only that, your query is using info from the cache table, but the part you're trying to replace is what creates the CTE `i` that ultimately fills such table.

If what you really want to do is to change the resultset returned from this SP, then the query you need to replace with your own is the one that's assigned to the @sqlStmt variable at the end, so instead of

```
SET @sqlStmt = 'select * from [cache].[' + @myName + ']'
```

you would have

```
SET @sqlStmt = 'SELECT tb_1.SubPart AS [Sub Part], SUM(tb_1.FinalItemSubPartQuantity) [Sub Part Quantity Needed], SUM(tb_1.FinalItemSubPartQuantity * tb_2.SalesWeek1) [Total Sales Week 1],...'
```

**Note the change of quoted aliases to square-bracketed ones*

If your query is meant to return information for a separate page, you should create another stored procedure with your query and then call this new SP from this separate page. This is of course if this cache table doesn't get emptied/deleted by a different process later on. If this is the case, then you're into a world of pain, as you would either need to duplicate this existing SP almost in its entirety into your new SP and change the output as stated above; add an optional parameter that determines wich output should this SP return (e.g. if the parameter is 1 the output is the same as now, but if the parameter is 2 the output is your query); or change this existing stored procedure to not return a value and make other(s) to calls this one and return information as needed. Probably the last option is the "least ugly" one.

Comment: I'll take a look at this in the morning and test it thanks. This stored procedure is actually a duplicate of one used for a different page and renamed and added the new name to the application. So, it is it's own stored procedure for the new page. I'll take a look at the changes explained so I can test it, thanks Josh!